# Disable vsync with GLFW?

Tags: c, windows, opengl, glfw

I use GLFW and GLEW; the problem is vsync is enabled by default, how can I shut it down?

- Windows 10
- Visual C++ 2019
- OpenGL 3.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you've made your GL context current via `glfwMakeContextCurrent()` you can use [`glfwSwapInterval(0)`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__context.html#ga6d4e0cdf151b5e579bd67f13202994ed) to request that vsync be disabled:

```
int main( int, char** )
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwInit();
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 640, 480, "GLFW", NULL, NULL );
    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );
    glfwSwapInterval( 0 );
    ...
```

Note that this is only a request, since your GL implementation may not support the underlying swap interval extension or vsync may be forced 'on' at the driver/OS level.

Comment: thanks a lot,When I close Vsync,A funny thing happened,My program Very simple ,Just Keep rotating a box , Every time my FPS goes down , eg:FPS 600 - FPS 200 ,,The box is going to be slow ; to be precise is When the Geforce Experience In-game coverage starts ,Why?

Comment: When I open Vsync ,That wouldn't have happened :<